# XML-RPC .NET call with associative array

Tags: c#, ruby, xml-rpc

I'm trying to perform some actions on a remote server using the XML-RPC .NET library and C#. I have no prior experience using this protocol but most examples seemed pretty straight forward. But the server I'm trying to communicate with seems to parse commands slightly different than most examples I've seen.

All calls are made using a `'perform_actions'` function and it expects a list of action(s) along side with it as parameter. Fortunately there's a pretty decent documentation with some code samples included but these examples are done in Ruby/Perl with which I have no experience. I've tried translating these to C# with which I believe I'm on the right path but I'm consistently getting the error`"Server returned a fault exception: [400] Invalid request: expected list of actions."`

My current code

```
    [XmlRpcUrl("https://DOMAIN/admin/rpc")]
    public interface iFace : IXmlRpcProxy
    {
        [XmlRpcMethod("perform_actions")]
        XmlRpcStruct[] perform_actions(XmlRpcStruct struc);
    }


    public void GetData()
    {
        XmlRpcStruct actions = new XmlRpcStruct();
        actions.Add("name", "registrations.accounts.list");

        iFace proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<iFace>();
        proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

        XmlRpcStruct[] response = proxy.perform_actions(actions);
    }
```

And here is a Ruby example from the API documentation which I was trying to replicate which is functional

```
require 'xmlrpc/client'

url = 'https://user:passwd@qmanage.example.com/admin/rpc'
c = XMLRPC::Client.new_from_uri(url)

# Call the action to list the access groups.
ags = c.call('perform_actions', [{
    'name' => 'network.accessgroups.list',
    'args' => {}
}])
```

The server doesn't really seem to recognize the `XmlRpcStruct` I'm sending as the error seems to complain about not receiving a list of actions. (I receive the same error if I send no parameter). However if I change the `XmlRpcStruct` to a regular string array it will complain about expecting a struct instead so the data isn't ignored entirely.

Is anyone able to help me in the right direction with my problem or does anyone know why this error is returned?

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to figure out my dilemma. Seems I had to pass an array of `XmlRpcStruct`'s rather than just singular `XmlRpcStruct`, the following solved my problem:

```
        XmlRpcStruct[] actions = new XmlRpcStruct[1];
        XmlRpcStruct action = new XmlRpcStruct();
        action.Add("name", "registrations.accounts.list");
        actions[0] = action;
```

I just passed `actions` as parameter to the `perform_actions` function.